# CKEditor height grow as use typing

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a ckEditor, and I want to make the height of the ckEditor auto grow as I am typing.

[image]

```
<textarea name="description" id="description">
</textarea>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );
    CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = [CKEDITOR.getUrl('contents.css'), CKEDITOR.getUrl('/js/ckeditor/skins/moono-dark/styles.css')];

</script>
```

Is there a way to do it via JS or CSS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Auto Grow](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/autogrow) addon.

> With this plugin, CKEditor will automatically expand and shrink
>   vertically depending on the amount and size of content entered in its
>   editing area.
>
> The following configuration options are available:
>
> [maximum](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-autoGrow_maxHeight) and [minimum](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-autoGrow_minHeight) editor height after adjustment to content,
>   [extra space](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-autoGrow_bottomSpace) to be added between content and editor bottom bar,
>   having auto grow happen [on editor startup](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-autoGrow_onStartup)
>
> Note: This plugin is designed to work only with the [classic editor](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed).